# Getting NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException when extends QueryDslRepositorySupport and multiple datasources

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, querydsl, multiple-databases

I need to use multiple databases.
I am using Spring Boot + Spring Data JPA, 
so I have two configuration classes:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.rest.dao.first",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "firstEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "firstTransactionManager")
public static class DnbbJdbcConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.first")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "firstEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource())
                .packages("com.rest.dao.first")
                .persistenceUnit("first")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "firstTransactionManager")
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory(builder).getObject());
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.rest.dao.second",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "secondTransactionManager")
public static class SmsJdbcConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.second")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondEntityManagerFactory")
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "second")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource())
                .packages("com.rest.dao.second")
                .persistenceUnit("second")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondTransactionManager")
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory(builder).getObject());
    }
}
```

I guess there is not error and correct.
So, when I use default repository then not error.
(e.g userRepository.findById() - not error in multi datasources)

But, When I use custom repository then error occur.
(https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations)

**Custom Implements**

```java
public class FirstRepositoryImpl extends QueryDslRepositorySupport implements FirstCustomRepository {

public FirstRepositoryImpl() {
    super(First.class);
}

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "first")
private EntityManager entityManager;

private QFirst first = QFirst.first;

@Override
public List<String> messages() {
    JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
    return query.from(first).list(first.message);
}   
}
```

**ExceptionTrace**

```java
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: firstEntityManagerFactory,secondEntityManagerFactory
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:582) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:541) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:707) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:680) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:178) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
... 45 common frames omitted
```

Did I misconfigure something?

I wrote sample code in my github repository..
https://github.com/okihouse/spring-boot-multiple-datasource-with-querydsl

Comment: the exception that you get is straight forward. You define two bean which are same type. to avoid such exceptio you can use @Qualifier(secondEntityManagerFactory) (where you want this bean is autowired) and   @Qualifier(firstEntityManagerFactory)

Comment: @Vaseph I try  `@PersistenceUnit(name = "firstEntityManagerFactory", unitName = "first")
 @Qualifier("firstEntityManagerFactory")
 private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;` but still error.

Comment: what error did you get now?

Comment: @Vaseph It is same error `No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: firstEntityManagerFactory,secondEntityManagerFactory`

I run debug and I found some code snippet in `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:582`  `findDefaultEntityManagerFactory` method  is default use EMF when not exist unitName, is that right? Why spring not excute `protected EntityManagerFactory findNamedEntityManagerFactory(String unitName, String requestingBeanName)` method??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved myself:

I'm check `QueryDslRepositorySupport.class` and found out.

```java
@PersistenceContext
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    Assert.notNull(entityManager);
    this.querydsl = new Querydsl(entityManager, builder);
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}
```

@PersistenceContext have not "unitName"
So, Spring can't inject EntityManager.

I create `QueryDslRepositorySupportWrapper.java`
and inject EntityManager manually.

And It works.

https://github.com/okihouse/spring-boot-multiple-datasource-with-querydsl

Comment: I recently ran into the same problem and this approach worked for me as well.